# loop over this array

Tags: php

```
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 22
        [name] => Data Management
        [slug] => data-management
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 22
        [taxonomy] => topic
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [term_id] => 24
        [name] => High Frequency Travel
        [slug] => high-frequency-travel
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 24
        [taxonomy] => topic
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 1
    )
```

)

And i want to get at the name entry.

I'm trying:

```
foreach ($topicArr as $i => $row) {
   echo $row['name'];
}
```

but i get an error saying Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in....I'm really not sure how I get around it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your row isnt an array, its an object, you should use the proper syntax to get members of objects:

```
foreach ($topicArr as $i => $row) {
   echo $row->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just change

```
echo $row['name'];
```

to

```
echo $row->name;
```